# PrimeFaces Tabview - Resize width of tabs

Tags: css, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, tabview

I have a Tabview that is left oriented.

[image]

I want to decrease the witdh of tabs headers, they are too large.
How can I do that?

```
<p:tabView orientation="left">
    <div style="width: 5%">
        <p:tab  title="Tab1">
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Tab2">
            <p:dataTable id="dg_Diger"
                value="#{aboneGoruntulemeProvider.digerModel}" var="diger"
                style="margin-bottom:20px">
                <p:column headerText="Kart No">
                  <h:outputText value="#{diger.kartNo}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Alt Limit">
                  <h:outputText value="#{diger.altLimit}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Veriliş Tarihi">
                  <h:outputText value="#{diger.verilisTarihi}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Bitiş Tarihi">
                  <h:outputText value="#{diger.bitisTarihi}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Durum">
                  <h:outputText value="#{diger.durum}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:tab>
    </div>
</p:tabView>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could override the CSS provided by PrimeFaces.

While the default values of the tabs are 25% and the panels are 75% of width, you can adjust the tabs header into 10% and the panels of the tabs to 90% which all together would build up a 100%.

```
/** tabs **/
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-left > .ui-tabs-nav {
   width: 10%;
}
/** panels **/
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-left > .ui-tabs-panels {
   width: 90%;
}
```

You have to make sure that you are cascading correctly.

Comment: It affects all the TabViews of the project. Can we have this applied only to one particular TabView?

Comment: you can set a `styleClass` on the desired tab and target that css class @BuddhikaAriyaratne